# spring mvc request URL mapping scanned twice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using component scan to scan all my controllers and annotation config for autowiring.
I am also using mvc:annotation driven and tx:annotation-driven. My web app runs fine but during startup all request mappings are scaned twice. I get the logs as below.

```
Mapped URL path [/mdm/searchDevice] onto handler 'mdmController'
2386 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO Mapped URL path [/mdm/searchDevice.*] onto handler 'mdmController'
2386 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO Mapped URL path [/mdm/searchDevice/] onto handler 'mdmController'
2760 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory - Finished initializing Tiles2 application context.
2386 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO Mapped URL path [/mdm/searchDevice.*] onto handler 'mdmController'
2386 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO Mapped URL path [/mdm/searchDevice/] onto handler 'mdmController'
```

/mdm/searchDevice/ is getting scaned twice.

My spring-servlet.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tcs.mpos">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <!-- <property name="order" value="0"/> -->
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: If i remove  <mvc:annotation-driven /> then logs shows only once the url mapping has been scaned

Comment: I think you can safely remove the `context:component-scan` as `mvc:annotation-driven` will also scan the controllers.

Comment: If i remove `context:component-scan` controller does not gets initialized at all. If i remove `mvc:annotation-driven` then controller does not generates Json objects for ajax responses.

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I have exactly same problem. Removing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` help, but I can't remove it